# How to customize an icon for an automator service?

Tags: macos, service, applet, automator

When you lauch a long running Service create with Automator on Mac (in my case 10.11.6) an tiny spinning cog appears ⚙ in the menubar, next to the wifi, sound & battery icons.

Just wondered, how is possible to customize that, if possible?

---

UPDATE:
What you told me got me curious, and looked for more into it. [One article](https://setapp.com/how-to/customize-menu-bar-on-mac) got my eye, and decided to just take a look inside the first-party StatusItems by Apple
`/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/`
and inside every Package Contents of those *.menu files and then compared them with looking inside my Service located inside
`username/Lybrary/Services`

Then I checked the contents of an app I previously made with AppleScript Editor, noticed that inside the service there is no Resources folder (it seems that it isn't enough to simple create that and drop an *.icns file into it).
So I noticed this lines inside the service Info.plist file

```
    <key>NSMenuItem</key>
    <dict>
        <key>default</key>
        <string>NameOfMyService</string>
    </dict>
    <key>NSMessage</key>
    <string>runWorkflowAsService</string>
```

And now I wonder, do I just need to add a few lines inside this plist to tie the icon to the menubar status item?

MAYBE something like this?

```
//self.statusBar.image =
```

Comment: That would be buried in the system frameworks, as it is also used for AppleScript progress.  How are you wanting to change it?

Comment: Something like an indicator applet, to show this particular service is active in the menubar.

Comment: That is what it is there for, or are you talking about a dedicated NSStatusItem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is a NSStatusItem, I just a noob. It's a simple service to keep my mac awake a with `caffeinate` command line and toggling it on and off.

Comment: Status items are those small menus on the right side of the menu bar, such as the progress (spinning gear) put up by Automator or AppleScript when they are running.

Comment: Interesting, so is there a way to create a custom NSStatusItem for a single app/applet/workflow?

Comment: Automator might not be very useful since it doesn't stay open, but AppleScript has access to most of the Cocoa API (including status item menus) via AppleScriptObjC.

Comment: My goal its to have a personalized icon, that mean I will use the default applescript status item (and rewrite my whole workflow into a applescript from scratch). Isn't it possible to simply add a couple of lines to the info.plist to associtate the icon to the menubar status item? Please take a look at what i updated above

Comment: For your update:  that **Info.plist** describes some details about the service, and doesn't have anything to do with an [NSStatusItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstatusitem).  The NSMenuItem mentioned is for the entry in the main system Services menu - see [Services Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/properties.html) for some information about those keys.  Your AppleScript application can implement a status item, but it takes a little more than a couple of lines in an Info.plist.